# Easy way to display constantly updating DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe I am updating in a loop and would like to see the updates live. What is the easiest, nicest-looking way for me to do this? Simply printing in a loop is too jenky looking, and `curses` won't work as I'm on windows (and doesn't seem like it would be that easy, anyways). I thought about using either matplotlib or bokeh to do it, but neither seems to have any support for displaying a dataframe (plenty of capability to *plot* one though).

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you in an IPython notebook?

Comment: This is meant to be a standalone application but I'm not against having it sit inside a notebook if it makes it easier.